# Laradock NGINX cannot start service

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, laradock

I had a working laradock docker container and wanted to add some services, when I tried to rebuild I get the following error:-

> ERROR: for laradock_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: Ports are not
> available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:81: bind: An attempt was made to access
> a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

I have tried to list services using port 81 but `lsof -i TCP:81` returned no results so i tried listing everything with `lsof -i` which returned

```
node     23 chris   18u  IPv4   1034      0t0  TCP localhost:38187 (LISTEN)
node     23 chris   21u  IPv4   1052      0t0  TCP localhost:38187->localhost:49786 (ESTABLISHED)
node     77 chris   18u  IPv4  18626      0t0  TCP localhost:49786->localhost:38187 (ESTABLISHED)
node     86 chris   18u  IPv4  22566      0t0  TCP localhost:49788->localhost:38187 (ESTABLISHED)
node    106 chris   19u  IPv4   1057      0t0  TCP localhost:38187->localhost:49788 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I thought it may be conflicting with my old setup so I have pruned everything and started from fresh with the latest release of docker desktop and laradock, still getting the same error and now i'm stuck and don't even have my old container to fall back on.

What can be causing this error?

Comment: In case you are not using root for the service it could prevent you to bind to ports lower than 1024, since they are reserved for system tasks. So i would assume you do not have permissions with the process to bind to port 81 in this case.

Comment: I have never had to build containers using root in the past but have tried it anyway, still getting the same error. (in case I am doing it wrong I used sudo docker-compose up -d nginx mysql meilisearch)

Comment: If it is possible, would you simply bind to a higher port, for instance 8080, to see if your container has permissions to bind to any port?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this within the laradock config, I thought I had changed the port at one point because I had a similar idea however it still tried to listen on 81

Comment: You should change the "host" part of the port binding, so in docker compose you can bind port 8080 of host, to port 81 of container and it should be ok

Comment: Ok, so I had previously changed the wrong port in the laradock .env, I should have changed VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT which I have now done and it has worked proving that you are correct with the permission binding, I wonder why it is suddenly a problem when it hasn't been in the past? Anyway thanks for the help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same issue user binding the host port 81 did not have enough permissions quickest fix was to change docker's host port inside port binding to above 1024 (we used 8080) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Docker nginx port issue: By default ubuntu install apache which run in 80 port. so just stop it. This can happen also for nginx. So follow same process.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

nginx:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/pos/static/
      - ./docker/nginx/development:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - backend
```